# How to create confluence page with JiraChart using Rest API

Tags: rest, jira, confluence-rest-api

I need to create a confluence page via REST API which contains a JIRA Chart

according to: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/JIRA+Chart+Macro and https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Confluence+REST+API+Examples

my implement code is

```
curl -u myusername:mypassword -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"type":"page","title":"A_Test_page","space":{"id":123456789,"key": "~myusername"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="jirachart">
  <ac:parameter ac:name="chartType">pie</ac:parameter>
  <ac:parameter ac:name="statType">assignee</ac:parameter>
  <ac:parameter ac:name="showinfor">true</ac:parameter>
  <ac:parameter ac:name="jql">Some JQL</ac:parameter>
  <ac:parameter ac:name="border">false</ac:parameter>
  <ac:parameter ac:name="server">My Jira Server Name</ac:parameter>
  <ac:parameter ac:name="serverId">144880e9-a353-312f-9412-e5028e8166fa</ac:parameter>  <!-- I don't have this information -->
</ac:structured-macro>
","representation":"storage"}}}' http://my.wiki.server/rest/api/content | python -mjson.tool
```

**The question is:** If I don't know "**serverId**", is there any alternative (eg: direct to JIRA url with authentication info...) or work-arround to get the JIRA Chart up on the page?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. What you could possibly do is query the REST api to get the serverId:

```
curl -u myusername:mypassword -X GET -H 'Accept: application/json' http://my.wiki.server/rest/applinks/1.0/listApplicationlinks | python -mjson.tool
```

Comment: Thanks, mattr.
I've tried your solution but got
{
    "message": "Only an admin can access this resource.",
    "status-code": 401
}

Comment: Finally, I've got ServerId and it works, but I asked this question because I could get Jira Issues without a ServerId as bellow:

<ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"jiraissues\">
 <ac:parameter ac:name=\"columns\">type,key,summary,assignee</ac:parameter>
 <ac:parameter ac:name=\"server\">my.jira.server</ac:parameter>
 <ac:parameter ac:name="anonymous">fasle</ac:parameter>
 <ac:parameter ac:name="url">
  <ri:url ri:value="my.jira.server/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-xml/temp/SearchRequest.xml?jqlQuery=my_jql" />
 </ac:parameter>
</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro

Comment: Oh, I assumed that you were an admin, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

there is also another (albeit not very elegant yet effective) way: just look in the source by querying the confluence rest api. Simply create whatever you want to accomplish in confluence first and then do a query to let confluence tell you the source:

```
curl -s -u user:pass -X GET "http://your.confluence.com/confluence/rest/api/content?title=testpage&spaceKey=SPACEKEY&expand=body.storage"
```